# How can I protect an HTTP POST request from only being received by an approved javascript client?

Tags: javascript, http, security, authentication, analytics

I have a URL that will accept POSTed data and store a record of it — this is for analytics. I need to secure that against anyone in the world from POSTing to it, but what possible authentication mechanism can I use that it is safe to expose the details of? I don't think the javascript can access any secret data without making it public.

I could base it off any HTTP header, but these can all be spoofed, right?

If it helps, both client and server are https.

Edit: I think I need to state the problem more explicitly; sorry, I thought I could explain it concisely, but it's clearly not coming across! Imagine the following:

1. A static page at `https://example.com/index.html` includes a script, `https://example.com/script.js`.
2. The script makes a request to another remote URL, e.g.

   ```
   ajax_call('https://stats.example.com/stats.php', 'some data');
   ```
3. The `stats.php` script simply writes `'some data'` to a file

Now, the flaw is that anyone can simply POST anything to `stats.php` and it will write to the file. I want to restrict that to just my 'client', i.e. `https://example.com/index.html`.

If I could, I would do something like this in `stats.php`:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] == 'https://example.com') {
    do_stuff();
} else {
    die('not allowed');
}
```

but I've always been under the impression that HTTP_REFERER (and other similar headers) could just be spoofed, so that woud be pointless.

Comment: Which kind of parameters is provided to the endpoint?

Comment: Currently, just a single parameter: url.

Comment: You don't have any informations tied to the current user? An application or anything?

Comment: You wrote: _How can I protect an HTTP POST **request** from only being **received** by an **approved javascript client**?_ Is a client receiving the request or a server? Or perhaps, you meant that the response to the request would only be delivered to a certified client?

Comment: @SamuelVaillant: Yes, there's a client: the javascript. But I can't just have a secure value embedded in the javascript, because that's world-readable.

Comment: Which back end do you use? In my company, we use node.js with some extra modules to get access to the environment variables, so we can extract a windows account from the request. That way we can compare it with active directory to know if users have access or not. Replace AD by some other database and windows account by anti-CSRF tokens sent by the server for public apps. Middleware like Express can easily be extended with a csrf module.

Comment: @Shilly The back end is PHP. But it's absolutely trivial code — literally, storing the value of a POST variable in a file. The problem is in securing that, and I believe that's independent of the backend. Are you accessing your backend via a javascript front-end? If so, how do you authenticate securely?

Comment: Google `PHP csrf token` for a multitude of articles explaining them and look at `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery`, prevention. Those tokens can be public and included inside a hidden form field in the HTML or as a cookie, or as a http header. Since only tokens generated by your PHP back end will be valid, the client cannot just spoof a random token without knowing how your server is configured.

Comment: "Since only tokens generated by your PHP back end will be valid, the client cannot just spoof a random token"

How does my client request a token in the first place? What prevents someone else from doing whatever that is?

Comment: @BobbyJack — Nothing. CSRF only stops an Attacker tricking a third-party User into making a request to your site which does something bad (like post spam to a forum). It doesn't stop the attacker attacking directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to secure that against anyone in the world from POSTing to it, but what possible authentication mechanism can I use that it is safe to expose the details of?

If the endpoint needs to be accessed by the browser of everybody who visits a public website, then you can't.

The browser is completely under the user's control. They can inspect everything the browser does. They can then recreate that using some other HTTP client.

If you trust the browser enough to let it make the request to your analytics API then you **must** trust the owner of the browser too. It is impossible to separate them.

---

The best you can do is analyse the data sent to the analytics API for usual or impossible patterns of behaviour.

Comment: I've also just reached this conclusion! Even if I could, then the only thing an 'attacker' really needs to do to 'spoof' those requests is keep refreshing the page anyway, so I guess it's not worth it. As you say, I'll just have to try to clean up any 'bad' data after the event.

Answer (score 0):

You Can USE `CORS` and so enable your BackEnd to receive ONLY REQUEST from a specific HOST/`DOMAIN`

Comment: Any idea which headers I'd be setting on the server? I'm already sending 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com' but that doesn't appear to prevent me from POSTing to that URL from elsewhere.

Comment: That will only stop attackers from launching attacks via third-party browsers. It won't stop them making requests directly from other HTTP clients.